# Splitting file by hex address

Tags: c#, .net

Im facing an difficulty while trying to split a file by hex address to hex address.
Its seems as though its splitting fine, but when i check the file, its always copying every byte from the start of the file not the start address.

Please let me know where i am going wrong
input string is hex address(string) converted to a long

```
    private void HexSplit(string inputFile, string outputFile, string startAddress, string endAddress)
    {
        FileStream hexReader = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
        FileStream hexWriter = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        long StartAddress = Convert.ToInt64(startAddress.ToUpper(), 16);
        long EndAddress = Convert.ToInt64(endAddress.ToUpper(), 16);

        int bytecount = 0;
        while (bytecount != EndAddress)
        {
            if (bytecount >= StartAddress && bytecount <= EndAddress) hexWriter.WriteByte((byte)hexReader.ReadByte());
            bytecount++;
        }

        hexReader.Close();
        hexReader.Dispose();
        hexWriter.Close();
        hexWriter.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "by hex address"? That is not a term that makes any sense to me. Do you have an example?

Comment: Have you debugged through the code? Is it correctly determining the start and end points? (And have you considered just using `hexReader.Position = StartAddress;` to skip the bytes you don't want to copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the input to have the reader positioned on the current starting point

```
byte b = hexReader.ReadByte();
if (bytecount >= StartAddress && bytecount <= EndAddress) 
    hexWriter.WriteByte(b);

bytecount++;
```

or you can use the [Filestream.Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position(v=vs.110).aspx) property to directly set the correct starting point avoiding to read unnecessary parts of the input file

```
long byteCount = StartAddress;
hexReader.Position = StartAddress;
while (bytecount <= EndAddress)
{
    hexWriter.WriteByte((byte)hexReader.ReadByte());
    bytecount++;
}
```

Notice that in both cases you should check for the input passed because if the addresses are bigger than the length of the file you will receive an exception

```
if(hexReader.Length < EndAddress)
   // Error message and return
```

Comment: Legend! your second method worked like a charm, thanks